# PHP POST variables in an iframe

Tags: php, post, iframe

I'm trying to post variables in a form to the form itself. The form has an iframe inside it which points to a php file(which has elements that I need to post too).

Here is an extract of the code:

```
  //clerkingpatient.php
  <?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $con = @pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=datamed user=admin password=admin ");

        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        $patient_no = test_input($_POST["patientNo"]);
        $complains = test_input($_POST["complains"]);
   }
   ?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" target="myframe" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
        <table cellpadding="5">
 <tr>  <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""/></td> </tr>
 <tr>  <td><input type="text" name="patientNo" value=""/></td> </tr>
 ...
 ...
 <tr><td>
             <iframe name="myframe" src="ttabcontrol.php"  width="1160px" height="200px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </td>    </tr>
<tr><td width="200px"><button type="submit" value="save" style="height: 35px">Save Data</button></td></tr>
        </table>
  </form>
```

The complains text field is in ttabcontrol.php

```
     //ttabcontrol.php
      <input type="text" name="complains" value="complains"/>
```

On submitting the form i get this error "Notice: Undefined index: complains in C:\wamp\www\bossmed\clerking\clerkingpatient.php on line 32"
What I'm doing wrong since I want to use the elements in the iframe.

Comment: Whats the point of the iframe?

Comment: You would probably need to use javascript to submit the form but set the action to the iframe rather than submitting the form back to the same page

Comment: You only need to set the `action` of your form to your `ttabcontrol.php`. Not `PHP_SELF`. Plus there's no way you can split a form across iframes.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how you might post data to an iframe without reloading the page perhaps you can make use of the following brief example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Post to an iFrame using Ajax</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>

            function ajax(m,u,p,c){
                /*
                    m=method
                    u=url
                    p=params {name:value}
                    c=callback
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call(this,xhr.response);
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post': p=params.join('&'); break;
                    case 'get': u+='?'+params.join('&'); p=null; break; 
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            function initialise(){
                var bttn=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')[0];
                    bttn.onclick=function(event){
                        var params={};
                        var fd=new FormData( document.forms['myform'] );
                        for( var key of fd.keys() ) params[key]=fd.get(key);
                        ajax.call( this, 'post', document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].src, params, cbfd );
                    };
            }

            function cbfd(r){
                var iframe=document.querySelectorAll('iframe[name="ifr"]')[0].contentWindow.document;
                iframe.body.innerHTML=r;
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',initialise,false);
        </script>
        <style type='text/css' charset='utf-8'>
            input[type='text']{
                margin:1rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='myform' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='field_1' value='value 1' />
            <input type='hidden' name='field_2' value='value 2' />
            <input type='hidden' name='field_3' value='value 3' />

            <input type='text' name='comment' placeholder='eg: we love javascript' />
            <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='eg: fred' />

            <input type='button' value='Post' />
        </form>
        <iframe name='ifr' src='iframesrc.php' width=600 height=400></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, for this example, the iframe is simply a php page like this:

```
<?php
    /* iframesrc.php */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        /* add in some random data at the iframe for fun and frolics */
        $_POST['date']=date( DATE_COOKIE );
        $_POST['ip']=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        echo json_encode( $_POST );
        /* 
         this script could do whatever processing was required
         with the post variables, any response is used by the 
         ajax callback
        */
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your solution is posting data to the iframe. But In my case there are elements that are in the iframe which I need to combine with the posted data. That is, patient name and number is posted from the form but the complain is in the iframe. How can I get all the data(including the elements in iframe) on clicking post?

Comment: ok - so you are saying that the iframe contains items ( form elements? ) that you need to include in the data you post to `clerkingpatient.php` script?

Comment: Yeah. Let me explain in detail. The form has some elements(Patient_name textfield, Patient_number textfield & a Post button) while the iframe has more elements(Compains text pane). I need to save all the data(name,number & complains) to the database on clicking the post button. Is there a way?